# event.touches is always undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ios, ipad

```
$(document).bind 'touchstart', (event) ->
    console.log event.touches
```

This is always undefined, I can't figure out why. As is `targetTouches`.

Any ideas? I'm testing on an iPad.

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your syntax looks weird to me but in regular javascript:

```
$(document).bind('touchstart', function(event) {
    console.log(event.originalEvent.touches);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, it's in coffeescript. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: +1 - took me a while to realize that jquery was not using the original event

Comment: thank you for the originalEvent addition - it works like magic :)

Comment: I also did not realize it was using the originalEvent! This saved me a tone of time.